# Simple javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

It turns out this does exactly what I want it to do. But HTML does not replace the function call with a value, which is why I got confused. The correct value IS passed into the array though. I am leaving this question here in case others have the same issue.

I have some javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $SAT = $SAT || [];
    $SAT.push(['setContent','subtype','sub']);
    $SAT.push(['setUser', '1234']);
</script>
```

but I want to replace 'sub' with a function call to retrieve the value by other means, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue() {
        return 'Some Value';
    }
    var $SAT = $SAT || [];
    $SAT.push(['setContent','subtype',getValue()]);
    $SAT.push(['setUser', '1234']);
</script>
```

however the resulting code does not replace the getValue() function call with 'Some Value' as I would have expected. Does anybody know why, and what I need to do to fix this?

Much appreciated!

Comment: do you want the value to be gotten every time you access the array or just once when you fill the array ?

Comment: Actually it does, ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/drJhx/)). May be you'll share more code with us?

Comment: Your code, as posted, does exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you reword?

Comment: @MichaelS Did you see the jsfiddle that Oybek made?  It works.

Comment: for the record...your code does what you want it to do.

Comment: You know what. It was in there all along, but HTML doesn't render the getValue() call into an actual value f what is returned from the call (obviously). I am just being a dumbass, thanks for the help guys! I hate javascript.

Comment: +1 for JavaScript troubles. We all have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an untested idea:

```
...
var get_val = function() {
    return "Hi.";
};
$SAT.push(['setContent', 'subtype', get_val()]);
// $SAT now has ['setContent', 'subtype', 'Hi.']
$SAT.push(['setUser', '1234']);
...
```

Comment: Nope. In this case the reference to the function will be passed instead of it's value.

Comment: yes, this only passes a reference to the function. Can you please edit to make it into a call to a function instead!

Comment: just change it to this: function get_val() {
    return "Hi.";
};

Comment: @MichaelS the way I have it is better (scope).

Comment: Noted. You just won yourself an accepted answer for improving my existing code!

Answer (score 2):

You can see here that your code does what you want
http://jsfiddle.net/SGBYY/